# How to save an array of different types of objects into database using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer

I am building a blog application for myself using `React`, `mongoose`, `node`, `express`, `multer`. I want to add whatever amount of images of paragraphs or images I like in the blog content. I am completely lost, I don't know how should I define the schemas and save them into the database. Also, I use `multer.any()` as middleware. I am not too sure whether `multer` will affect non-image data

Now let me try to upload only one image and one paragraph, I use console.log to check the result.

```js
const BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    coverImage: {
        type: String,
    },
    blogImage: {
        type: String,
    },
    lastModified: {
        type: String,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
    },
    blogContent: {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed, // this is the content where I can insert images and paragraphs
    }
})
```

routes

```js
const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
    },
});

router.patch(/:id, upload.any(), (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.blogContent);    // Output --> [object Object],[object, Object]
  console.log(req.files);   // Output --> []
})
```

server.js

```js
require("dotenv").config({path: "./config.env"});
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

// Connect DB
connectDB();


// express middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/blog', require('./routes/blogPage'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))

// handle error
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
    console.log(`Logged Error: ${err}` )
    server.close(() => process.exit(1))
})
```

I get a weird output from `req.body.blogContent` and get no output from `req.files` even though it should be there. I really need help for this!

Comment: Can you add the app.js file ? it seems you are not using bodyparser.

Comment: Yeap, I used express.json() and express.urlencoded() in my server.js file